# Is it okay to throw paper towels & rags with mineral spirits in the trash bin?

Tags: painting, safety

Newbie painter here. Is it okay to throw rags and paper towels that soaked mineral spirits into a plastic bag and then into the trash can?

Comment: You should leave them out in the sun away from your home to let the volatile components evaporate first.

Comment: The problem is, if I left the paper towels outdoors, they would blow away.

Comment: Mineral spirits alone will not "spontaneously combust". Oils, particularly unsaturated oils like those found in oil-based wood stains and finishes, will. **Let them dry out** in a safe outdoor area before tossing, they won't blow away because you are smart and will place a brick or stone on them. Or put them in a metal can with a lid, away from combustibles.

Comment: It's best to make it a habit that anything containing oil, resin or solvent is a fire hazard either through fume ignition or spontaneous combustion. Shove it in a tin can away from combustion sources and combustible materials till it dries or polymerizes, if it's that windy weigh the thing down with a rock. I've seen epoxy heat to the point it smoked, the term is exothermic. As my grandfather's Ready Kilowatt sticker said, "Think safety, work safely".

Comment: I am actually using Klean Strip Odorless Mineral Spirits (which smell far from being odorless) and Minwax Helmsman Spar Urethane in this scenario. I'm not sure if the Urethane is oil-based, but I will dry everything out just to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not safe. The plastic bag will most likely make it worse. I have seen just an open pile of rags (not bagged) smoldering in a jobsite waste can at the end of a work day. I removed them and set the pile in the yard just to be safe, it was a pile of ashes in the morning.

Comment: Short of setting the paper towels on fire, how can I dispose of them?

Comment: @Kyle do you have an ash can? I bought a mini galvanized can (maybe 3 gallon) many years ago. It never rusts, and I can put hot coals and other flammable things in it without worrying about setting my grass (or house) on fire.

Comment: What I do in these cases when I am staining with oil based products, I open the rags, drape them over the edge of my trash can, single layer, and other places if I don't care if the stain, or in your case, paint, doesn't matter if it gets around. Let them dry, then dispose of them.

Comment: I don't have an ash can @Snowman but maybe now's the time to buy one

Comment: So just to be clear, as long as they are dried @Jack, the towels/rags are good to go in the trash then?

Comment: Yes, but I still do not put them in the trash in a bunch, After what I seen, it is nothing to take chances with.

Comment: @Jack what do you mean by don't put them away in a bunch? Should I make sure the dried towels are not touching in the trash?

Comment: Do not leave the even the dried rags in a clump (bunch), separate them so one rag does not lay upon another. My southern Maryland dialect may be getting in the way....

Comment: I appreciate the info, I just like step-by-step instructions so I can ensure I am not goofing.